# how to make a batch file or similar to operate putty in windows?

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, ssh, putty

I want to make a batch file or similar to operate putty.exe through my Windows 7 machine and do following :

```
open putty.exe(which is on linux(host) system)
enter host
enter user in "login as"
enter password in "password"
```

and when logged in 
    change directory to /opt

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p host=enter host
set /p user=set user
putty.exe -ssh %user%@%host%
```

You cant pass password directly to putty.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot easier to save your PuTTY settings and just load them, however you can use the command line switches for putty.exe within a batch file... See below:

```
@echo off
start putty.exe -telnet user@host -pw password
pause>nul
exit
```

Change the -ssh to one of the connection parameters. - See below for your options and how you should format it. However with some like "SSH" I don't think you can send passwords, plus you might need the auth keys.

```
putty.exe [-ssh | -telnet | -rlogin | -raw] [user@]host
```

Also found a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password) upon researching this further.

Comment: I would like to add that putty `-pw` flag should be used with care as the password could be seen by anybody or any process running on the machine.

Comment: Of course it's not the most secure way and I wouldn't advise having a batch file for everyone to see, maybe convert to .exe before deployment.

Comment: The problem is not the password being visible on the `.bat`, but that other users (or processes) can retrieve the process list and see the arguments passed to putty.

Comment: the batch file will be on my local PC so i think its safe.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need Putty, use this Script

```
@echo off
title SSH Connecter
echo With this Programm you can easily connect to a Computer with SSH (Local Network)
pause
cls
set /P computer="Enter the name of the Computer: "
set /P username="Enter the Username: "
cls
ssh %username%@%computer%
```